# KVM Networking performance

Tags: centos, networking, kvm

I am using KVM over centos7. My question is regarding networking issue that I am having in my setup.

I am using `Bridge Br1: Host device vnet0` for all kvm instances.
I have instance 1 and 2-5. Where 1 communicate with all 2-5 instances, the communication is full duplex. Instances 2-5 don't communicate each other.
At certain point the network goes down and it takes sometime to come up again.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was STP, that I needed to enable so that packets do not create loops.
So once STP is enabled that loop is broken and system with KVM infrastructure works fine.